# How to concatenate I18n.t() strings in content_for() helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to concatenate the strings from my localization file "admin.titles.index" and "%{model_name}" (which takes from activerecord.models.harddisk).

I tried with:

```
<% title = I18n.t("admin.titles.index") + I18n.t("%{model_name}", 
           model_name: admin.model_name, 
           pluralized_model_name: admin.model_name.pluralize)%>

<% content_for(:title, title) %>
```

But I get an error message:

```
translation missing: de.%{model_name}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a translation for a string, that you pass in `I18n.t`. As long as you don't have a translation for `"%{model_name}"` you'll get the error message.

In your case, you can just concatenate the string from localization with your model name:

```
<% title = I18n.t("admin.titles.index") + admin.model_name %>
```

Otherwise, you need to provide a translation for `model_name` in `yml` file. For example:

```
en:
  model_name: "English %{model_name}"
de:
  model_name: "German %{model_name}"
```

and then use it as

```
I18n.t("admin.titles.index") + I18n.t("model_name", model_name: admin.model_name)
```